# why even after adding the -url: /images in app.yaml, i can't access /images/med-9.png ,

Tags: python, image, jinja2

I am learning python, specifically web development using python, and am following the course cs253 in udacity, now after performing the unit 4 excercise, i want to add an image in my html template, i have made a directory : "Templates" in my "hellowebappworld" directory which is the directory being hosted by app engine and inside templates, i've made a folder : "images" where i have my image. even after adding the url : / images and static_dir: images m not able to access the image

this is my app.yaml:

```
application: hellowebappworld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /images
  static_dir: images 

- url: .*
  script: main.py

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

following is the main.py:

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2
from google.appengine.ext import db

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader =            jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape=True)

class Art(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    art = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)



class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)
    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)
    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class MainPage(Handler):
    def render_front(self, title="", art="", error=""):
        arts = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Art ORDER BY created DESC")
        self.render("front.html", title=title, art=art, error = error, arts     = arts)
    def get(self):
        self.render_front()
    def post(self):
        title = self.request.get("title")
        art = self.request.get("art")
        if title and art:
            a = Art(title = title, art = art)
            a.put()
            self.redirect("/")
        else:
            error = "we need both a title and some artwork!"
            self.render_front(title,art,error)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

and finally my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>/ascii/</title>

    </head>
    <body>
<form method="post">
    <label>
        <div>title</div><input type="text" name="title" value= {{title}}>
    </label>
    <label>
        <div>art</div><textarea name="art"> {{art}} </textarea>
    </label>
    <div class="error"> {{error}}</div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<hr>
    {% for art in arts %}
    <div class="art">
        <div class="art-title">{{art.title}}</div>
        <pre class="art-body">{{art.art}}</pre>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <img src="/images/med-9.png">
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try modifying your app.yaml file to this..

```
- url: /templates/images
  static_dir: templates/images
```

On a side note, I like to structure my static files like so..

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

then my static folder is located in the root directory of my app engine app.

- Desktop

  - ProjectFolder

    - static

      - images
      - js
      - css
    - templates
    - main.py
    - app.yaml